# How to add R^2 and P-values to ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have created a graph with the follow code:

`ggplot(data.frame, aes(x=Score, y=Year, col=Position)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)`.

The plot is shown below. I'd like to add Pearson r values and P-values if possible to the accompanying label table or a new table on the graph? Adding the P-values is more important than the Pearson r's. Can anyone help me with this?

A sample of the data for reproducibility:

```
Year   Position   Score
2010   QB         16.5
2011   QB         15.4
2012   QB         16.1
2013   QB         14.3
2014   QB         13.8
2010   RB         14.2
2011   RB         13.9
2012   RB         13.9
2013   RB         11.8
2014   RB         11.6
2010   WR         11.4
2011   WR         12.4
2012   WR         10.4
2013   WR         8.8
2014   WR         9.7
```

:[image]

Comment: Add some example data to make this a more [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1)

Comment: Good idea, I realized having all positions would be way too much sample data so I just did three positions

Answer (score 2):

Check out `ggpmisc::stat_fit_glance()`

Without a reproducible example I can't give a perfect code, but it should look something like this.

```
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(data.frame, aes(x=Score, y=Year, col=position_new.y)) +
geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) +
stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm', geom = 'text', aes(label = paste0('p = ', round(..p.value.., 3))), label.x.npc = 0.4, label.y.npc = 1) +
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a reproducible example

Comment: I got an error `Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: It seems that `data` is `NULL` in your case.

Comment: @aocall, yep, it was null. Now my problem is that it is rounding p-values below 0.001 to 0. Is it posisble to have these p-values show up in the table of labels?

Comment: Try changing `round(..p.value.., 3)` to `format(..p.value.., 3)`

Comment: @aocall, that put them into scientific notation and now has ~7sigfigs.

Comment: Well... Perhaps you can tweak the call to `round` or `format` to produce suitable text?

Comment: @aocall, I'm confused what that means

Comment: Given that you now know which bit of code formats the labels, can you not devise a solution yourself?

Comment: @aocall, the format I'm looking for is a table on my graph somewhere, or integrated with the table of labels of positions. I don't know which part of code formats those tables, but could manually do it once I get a little push from StackOverflow

Comment: The p-values shown on the plot are formatted by `round`, since `label` is set to the result of that call. The problem with your questions is that you do not seem to be asking *how*, you are merely asking for us to do your work for you. To change the legend table, look into `scale_color_discrete`. To change how the p-values are formatted, change the call to round.

Comment: For example, you could try this: `stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm', geom = 'text', aes(label = paste0('p = ', ifelse(..p.value.. >= 0.001, round(..p.value.., digits = 3), "< 0.001"))), label.x.npc = 0.4, label.y.npc = 1)`